# Разработка компонента Joomla

Tags: joomla, php, компоненты

Появилась необходимость разработать компонент для Joomla, подскажите, где почитать про то, как устроена Joomla изнутри (Структура компонента в Joomla, Описание структуры файлов), желательно по версии 1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю насколько документация подходит к 1.7,но вот [посмотрите](http://joomla-book.ru/development).